# Unable to fetch data from table of mdb file using JDBC in Java

Tags: java, ms-access, jdbc

I am trying to fetch the data from Table of `.mdb` file. I am able to connect to the file but when i execute the query I get the following error.

```
java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Record(s) cannot be read; no read permission on
```

However, if I open the `.mdb` file directly with same user login I can view/edit the table.

Following is the code which I am writing,

```
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(database, "", "");
Statement s = conn.createStatement();
String selTable = "SELECT * FROM myTable";
ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery(selTable);
```

What I am doing wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You cut off the end of the error message. Are you really trying to read from a table called `myTable`, or are you actually trying to read from some other table? (One of the `MSys...` tables, perhaps?)

Comment: I am reading from myTable only.

Answer (score 0):

If your access database hasn't any username you can get connection without it. Can you try this:

conn = DriverManager.getConnection(database);

Answer (score 0):

If you are prompted for a username and password when you open the database in Access then the database has "user-level security" enabled. If that is the case then you should supply the username and password of an appropriate Access user as part of the connection string. For some examples, look [here](http://connectionstrings.com/access).